# SSRS: Compare with a specific time on the previous day

Tags: reporting-services, datediff, dateadd

IN SSRS, I am trying to find any records for which the associated date (shown as **adm.ts** in the code below) is anytime between 4:00 PM on the previous day and the time the report is run. I have tried the following code (in which I combined DateAdd() with TimeSerial()), but the expression returns '#Error':

```
=CountDistinct
   (IIf(Fields!adm_ts.Value > (DateAdd("d",-1, Today()) + TimeSerial(16,0,0)),
    Fields!vst_ext_id.Value, 
    Nothing), 
"HRTS_data")
```

I have also looked into using DateDiff() instead of DateAdd(), but was not successful there either. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:
`DateAdd("h", 16, DateAdd("d", -1, Date))`

Comment: Thanks @CB_Ron! I did have to substitute Today() for the last 'Date' argument in your expression, but it looks to be working now. I don't quite follow the logic, though. Can you explain what's going on?

Comment: Sure. The order of operations dictates that the inner `DateAdd` will be evaluated first, which gives us yesterday's date with the hour being 00:00:00. The outer `DateAdd` then takes that value and adds 16 hours to it, giving us for example `08/11/2020 16:00:00` or 4:00PM. Please mark my answer as correct if it helped you. Thanks!

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much!